# wxPython: Enabling and disabling widgets dynamically, getting settings from a csv file

Tags: python, dictionary, casting, widget, wxpython

I have a small program with many widgets like checkboxes, textctrls, statictexts,...

The values of all my widgets are stored in a dictionary. I'm saving the settings, e.g. this dictionary in a csv file. When I'm importing the settings from this file and update my dictionary, all my widgets should be enabled or disabled depending on the value in the dictionary by calling "def enable_controls". But the widgets are always enabled, even if the value is "False".

Here is the code snippet:

```
def enable_controls(self):
    self.Checkbox1.SetValue(bool(config.StartValues['Checkbox1']))
    self.Checkbox1TextCtrl.Enable(bool(config.StartValues['Checkbox1']))
    self.Checkbox1StaticText.Enable(bool(config.StartValues['Checkbox1']))

    self.Checkbox2.SetValue(bool(config.StartValues['Checkbox2']))
    self.Checkbox2TextCtrl.Enable(bool(config.StartValues['Checkbox2']))
    self.Checkbox2StaticText.Enable(bool(config.StartValues['Checkbox2']))
```

When I don't assign the value dynamically, it works:

```
def enable_controls(self):
    self.Checkbox1.SetValue(False)
    self.Checkbox1TextCtrl.Enable(False)
    self.Checkbox1StaticText.Enable(False)

    self.Checkbox2.SetValue(False)
    self.Checkbox2TextCtrl.Enable(False)
    self.Checkbox2StaticText.Enable(False)
```

Am I doing the type conversion to bool correctly?

Edit: This is how I write and read from my csv file:

```
def onButtonSave(self, event):
    import csv
    getValues(self, StartValues)
    writer = csv.writer(open('Test.csv', 'wb'))
    for key, value in sorted(config.StartValues.items()):
        writer.writerow([key, value])

def onButtonLoad(self, event):
    import csv
    reader = csv.reader(open('Test.csv', 'rb'))
    config.StartValues = dict(x for x in reader)
    enable_controls(self)
```

Comment: What data is stored in the StartValues dictionary and. In what way?

Comment: If they are all enabled, it looks like you're not passing booleans, but other type. I gues this one has to do with the previous question I answered. In that case, if you're getting the values straight from the CSV file, most probably they are strings, and any non-empty string evaluates as `True`. Note that this means `bool("False")` is `True`! You'd be better with something like `cb2 = "true" == config.StartValues['Checkbox2'].lower()`. The `lower` is there to catch all possible capitalizations of the word, but beware of typos...

Comment: If you didnt need a csv format specifically to be human readable, using cPickle would be more efficient since its maintains all your object types. You would avoid having to cast your string values back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said up in the comments, don't use `bool(config.StartValues['Checkbox2'])` to do the data conversion. `bool` returns `True` for anything that does *not* evaluate to `0`, `0.0` or an empty sequence or map. In this case, strings like `"True"` and `"False"` will both evaluate to `True`

Using string comparison or similar would be better, but beware of user-introduced typos if you let them edit the files!

Edit: use example...

```
def evalBooleans(value):
    """Assumes we're getting either booleans or strings!"""
    return (value if isinstance(value, bool)
                else value.lower() == "true")

cb2 = evalBooleans(config.StartValues['Checkbox2'])
self.Checkbox2.SetValue(cb2)
self.Checkbox2TextCtrl.Enable(cb2)
self.Checkbox2StaticText.Enable(cb2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ricardo! That's what i was guessing, that all values are evaluated to 'True'. But I don't really get how I should use the 'cb2 = "true" == config.StartValues['Checkbox2'].lower()' part in my code

Comment: Edited to include an example. The `cb2` part was just to reduce the number of times you convert the value! :D

Comment: You may also, instead, convert the values when you read them, and then use them normally everywhere else in the code.

Comment: it works! but only like this: `def evalBooleans(self, value): return value == "True"` The first letter of True and False is a capital letter, so I don't need the `.lower()`

Comment: Yeah, of course :) It's just, as I told you, a way to protect agains users typing "true" or "TRUE" in the file! :D

Comment: Mmh... interesting, which kind of crash? I understand that the values stored into `config.StartValues` are all strings, and so all them should work with `.lower()`. Anyway, just to be explicit: `evalBooleans` works the way I wrote it assuming you pass strings that are either `True` or `False` (no matter the capitalization)

Comment: Yes, the strings are `True`or `False`. The program crashes immediately after starting it.

Comment: Without knowing the reason for the crash (the exception at the end of the traceback would do), there's not much I can tell you :)

Comment: I found this while debugging: `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'lower'`

Comment: Mmh... That means you're passing a true boolean (ie. `True` or `False`) to the function, not a string, and in that case there's no need for a casting to other type? Let's change the function then...